# Grails Spring Security 1.2.1 and eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication

Tags: grails, spring-security, password-protection

I am interested in clearing the plain-text password from the Credentials object after a successful authentication, and was wondering what the best method to do this is?  It looks like it might be setting the eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication property on the ProviderManager object, but it is non-obvious how to do that in the Spring Security plugin.

Comment: Dave, did you see my answer below?

Comment: I did, it looks like it is going to work. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have found to set this property is to do so during Bootstrap. In BootStrap.groovy in the init closure add the following two lines:

```
def ctx = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getAttribute(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);

ctx.authenticationManager.setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(true)
```

I have tested this on Grails 1.3.7.

Comment: BootStrap supports dependency injection, so you could just add `def authenticationManager` as a field and call `authenticationManager.eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = true` in `init()`

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to achieve in the latest version of the Spring Security plugin (1.2.7). Simply add this setting to `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerManager.eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication = true
```

It appears this option was added for release 1.2.2 of the plugin.